# How to save image which is specific area that I clicked of picture Control?

Tags: c++, mfc, save-image

Hello I'm studying MFC and I wanna know how to save a specific part of image which is in Picture Control when I click.

Here is the sequence what I want to do

I already make a function that when I click grab button, it shows the image in picture control.

After that, I want to save image when I click specific area.

I attach the image to help understand.
[image: picture control]

"I want to know how to save the surrounding area as an image when I click a specific part of the picture control as shown above."

It would be easy problem, but I'd appreciate it if you understand because it's my first time doing this.

I tryed to use ScreenToClient function, but I failed.

Comment: There is no magic function that does all of what you need. You need to handle the button click, then you have to determine the rectangle to extract the image. For this, you should not need ScreenToClient, because the coordinates in a click event are already in client space. Then find functions that do the rest: extract an image, save to a file (the latter is non-trivial since you will certainly use a particular file format).

Comment: The exact same question was closed yesterday. The closure reason stated issues with the question you will need to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do this, but the general idea is usually pretty much the same:

1. Get a DC to the screen or the window's client area (aka DC1).
2. Create a DC compatible with DC1 (aka DC2).
3. create a CBitmap compatible with DC1, of the size you want to copy/save.
4. select the bitmap into DC2.
5. bitblt the area you care about from DC1 to DC2.
6. Create a CImage object.
7. Detach the bitmap from the CBitmap, and attach it to the CImage.
8. Use CImage::Save to save the bitmap to a file.

There are variations (e.g., writing the data to a file without using a CImage), but they tend to be tedious, and unless you're willing to put quite a bit of effort into things, fairly limited as well. e.g., writing a .BMP file on your own isn't terribly difficult, but is a bit tedious.If you want to support writing JPEG, TIFF, PNG, etc., you either need to integrate a number of libraries, or else write quite a bit of code for the file formats. CImage is somewhat limited as well, but at least supports a half dozen or so of the most common formats (and most people find just JPEG, PNG and possibly GIF sufficient).

Here's a bit of tested sample code for saving a 200x200 chunk of whatever's displayed in the current view window into a file named `capture.jpg`:

```cpp
void CPicCapView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {

    // width and height of area to capture
    static const uint32_t width = 200;
    static const uint32_t height = 200;

    CClientDC dc(this);

    CDC temp;
    temp.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

    CBitmap bmp;
    bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, width, height);
    temp.SelectObject(&bmp);

    // x-width/2, y-width/2 to get area centered at click point
    temp.BitBlt(0, 0, width, height, &dc, point.x- width/2, point.y-height/2, SRCCOPY);

    CImage dest;
    dest.Attach((HBITMAP)bmp.Detach());

    // for the moment, just saving to a fixed file name
    dest.Save(L".\\capture.jpg");

    CView::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

It might initially seem like you should be able to create the CImage object, use its `Create` to create a bitmap, and then blit directly from the screen bitmap to the CImage bitmap. Unfortunately, CImage's BitBlt uses the CImage as a source, not a destination, so although there may be some way to get this to work, the obvious method doesn't.